# jQuery Mobile URL converting hash (#) to %23 on Android browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile Multiple-Page template for my website but when I visit the website from Android browser it is not working.

The problem is that, the browser converting `#` tag to `%23`.

For example I can visit this link `www.domain.com/abc.php?id=1234#show_map` in iPhone but Android shows this link like this : `www.domain.com/abc.php?id=1234%23show_map`

How can I solve this problem? Should I create new page instead hash tag page or how can I add an exception for Android browsers?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code that doesn't work on Android, but works everywhere else:

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        window.done_mapping=false;
        contingency = function() {
            if(window.done_mapping) return true;
            window.location.href='#roast_map';
            window.location.reload();
        }
        contingency_email = function() {
            if(document.getElementById("email")) return true;
            window.location.href+='#email';
            window.location.reload();
        }
    </script>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
            <li class="goMap"><a href="#roast_map" data-transition="slide" onclick="contingency();">View on map</a></li>
            <li class="goMap"><a href="#email" data-transition="slide" onclick="contingency_email()">E-mail Results</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try encoding your URL ?

Comment: As far as I can tell the Android browser handles fragment identifiers just fine. Are you sure you are not encoding the hash character on the server-side by accident? Can you post a real URL that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Here is my js code : 
 

    `<script type="text/JavaScript">
            window.done_mapping=false;
            contingency = function() {
                if(window.done_mapping) return true;
                window.location.href+='#roast_map';
                window.location.reload();
            }`

HTML : 

    `<li class="goMap"><a href="#roast_map" data-transition="slide" onclick="contingency();">View on map</a></li>`

Comment: Don't add the hash the end of the href. Try setting `window.location.hash` instead.

Comment: where do i set window.location.hash? inside a script tag ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery encode/decode method you should use to encode a url that contains special characters. for example:

var url = 'www.domain.com/abc.php?id=1234#show_map';
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url);

Comment: I think `encodeURIComponent` is a native javascript function, not a jQuery method.