# jquery mobile #someLink not working in android browser

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, android-webview

i am creating a basic html5 jquery mobile webpage that uses 3 jquery mobile pages where users can naviagte to depending on the href they click on.

in the safari and google chrome web browser this feature works perfect i.e it will load the correct page using:

```
<li>
    <h3>Type:</h3>
    <h4><a href="#itemTypeList" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Select Type</a></h4>
  </li>
```

In this case it will load #itemTypeList page that is inside the same html5 file as the above code that invoked the web request call.

For some bizare reason this call does work on an android webview. It never displays or even attempt to display the #itemTypeList page

here is the itemType page

```
<div data-role="page" id="itemTypeList">
  <div data-role="header" data-inset="true" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" > <a href="" onclick="history.back(-1); return false;">Back</a>
    <h1>Item type</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"  data-scroll="true" id="itemtypeList">
      <li><a href="hello1.html">hello 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="hello2.html">hello 2/a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the orginal content page tht gets displayed initially

```
div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
  <div data-role="header" data-inset="true" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" > <a href=""  onclick="history.back(-1); return false;">Back</a>
    <h1><span style="margin-left:1em">Item Detail</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="itemFieldslist" data-inset="true"  data-scroll="true" >
      <li data-role="list-divider">
        <h2>Item Detail Title</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Type:</h3>
        <h4><a href="#itemTypeList" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Select Type</a></h4>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Some Field</h3>
        <h4>e3e3e3e</h4>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I have had same problem long time ago, using hashtag on android device was giving error for browser. Let me check how I solved it

Comment: Is it similar to this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798731/jquery-mobile-url-converting-hash-to-23-on-android-browser

Comment: have you tried it with `$.mobile.changePage()`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/B8JDt/

Comment: Gok, yes i cant use #someLink in android. i tried the above Script u posted ie $('ul a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'), {
        transition: 'flip'
    });
}); and it did not work unless i am missing something?

Comment: Any other advice? still does not work on android

Comment: JavaScript has decodeURIComponent function, try it. I don't know exactly how to use it. In Jquery I saw an example like this also : $("#quote1 span").html(decodeURIComponent(text1));

You need to decode your URL somehow. I didn't do web for long time, I forgot many things sorry

Comment: Please see if you can dig the piece of code that fixes this. thanks